# Manually install Java plugin

Tags: ubuntu, java, calendar

I'm trying to install this plugin: http://www.aleks.com/downloads/linux_jvm , and cannot seem to find the correct directory to put it in. I'm using Ubuntu 10.10, and when I run the following, I get the following:

```
josh@josh-ubuntu:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.7) (6b20-1.9.7-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Can anyone advise? Do I need a different Java?

Comment: I'd guess either somewhere in /usr/lib/jvm or in /usr/java. I don't have that version of Ubuntu... It must be a directory called "ext" in a directory called "lib". you can search for all ext directories with `locate` or with `find / -name ext`

Comment: @mihi: Found it, thanks! It was at: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/lib/ext Would you like to change your comment into an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wrote it again as an answer so that you can accept it. You could have also written an answer yourself and accepted it, if you liked ...]

I'd guess either somewhere in `/usr/lib/jvm` or in `/usr/java`. I don't have that version of Ubuntu... It must be a directory called "ext" in a directory called "lib". you can search for all ext directories with `locate` or with `find / -name ext`